# How to install MySQL on Leopard, Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I followed [this](http://hivelogic.com/articles/view/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x) tutorial to the very end, then found out it didn't work right. I think I have everything installed but when I type

```
mysql -uroot
```

I only get

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

**Note:** I did not skip the "Setting the Path" step. Upon running this command for the first time:

```
mate ~/.bash_login
```

This brought up an empty file. So I added this line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I saved the file, closed TextMate, executed the following command:

```
. ~/.bash_login
```

...and continued with the tutorial. Based on your suggestions, I thought maybe the file didn't actually get saved. So I ran the following command to bring up the file again:

```
mate ~/.bash_login
```

...yet the contents of the file were as they should be.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't have the mysql binaries in your path.

The link you posted has a section on setting the path, titled "Setting the Path Do not skip this step! Most everything else will fail if you do."

EDIT: As debugging steps, try:

- First launching a new terminal window. Does it run now?
- Typing "echo $PATH" at the prompt. Does the path show up correctly as you've typed it in bash_profile?
- Running it the long way: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
  Does the application run?

Comment: You beat me by 34 seconds.  +1.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not skip that step. The file is intact. Any other suggestions for me to try?

Comment: typing "echo $PATH", I get /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/pear/bin (no mysql in path). running the long way, I get a different issue: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: @Andrew, then you did not follow the step of the tutorial that you claim to have followed, because if you did, /usr/local/sbin and /usr/local/mysql/bin would be in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the step that says

> Setting the Path
>
> Do not skip this step! Most everything
>   else will fail if you do.

Did you close your terminal window and re-open it afterwards?

Update:
What does "which mysql" say?  Does "ls /usr/local/mysql/bin" say?

Comment: And for the suggestion to close and re-open the terminal

Comment: What do you mean by "The file is intact".  The step was about setting your PATH.  Is it set?  And note, this is NOT case insensitive.

Comment: "which mysql" returns nothing."ls /usr/local/mysql/bin" returns a bunch of stuff. mysql is one of those things in the list. is that the executable that needs to be run?

Comment: That's proof positive that you did not set up the path.  Go back and follow those instructions completely and accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Try editing `~/.profile` (rather than `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`).
- You may find it easier to use the native Mac style .dmg installer [directly from Sun](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg).

One nice thing about the dmg installer is that it automagically sets up symlinks to /usr/local/mysql (which means less - or no - fiddling with your $PATH).

Comment: Thanks, I tried using .profile instead, but it did not work. When I run "echo $PATH" it returns "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/pear/bin." Those must be getting set somewhere, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use **[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info)**.

It has Apache, PHP and MySQL packaged with no further setup necessary.

Comment: I've used MAMP, but I'd rather install them separately

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is usually put in /usr/local/mysql/bin/

You need to add this to your PATH, you can do this by adding the follwoing lines to your .bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
export PATH
```

The .bash_profile file is located in the root of your username directory.

Make sure you restart your Terminal for the setting to take affect.

Comment: Yeah, that's already in the tutorial that he supposedly followed.  Makes you wonder how well he followed it, doesn't it?

Comment: The tutorial mentioned .bash_login which, at least on my Mac, is not there.  Figured that could be a point of confusion.

Comment: your approach is a little different than the tutorial, what is the difference between yours and: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a difference. I just find that having each thing you add to PATH on a separate line is more manageable; especially when you are adding several items to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're not a command-line person, I highly recommend you also install the MySQL Preference Pane to start/stop the server and install Sequel Pro to create databases and run queries.

ftp://ftp.mysql.com/pub/mysql/download/gui-tools/MySQL.prefPane-leopardfix.zip

http://www.sequelpro.com/